# Python multiprocessing creates new memory location

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm having a problem with python's `multiprocessing` package. I've tried to simplify things as much as possible with the following example. We have 2 memory banks. Each has its own "separate" memory (`mem`) which is a `dict`. They also have access to shared memory (`shared_mem`), which is an `mp.Array`. After computing, the `mem`s are filled with 3 entries, and the `shared_mem` should be equal to the entry-wise product of the two separate `mem`s. We expect each `mem` to be `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}` and `shared_mem` to be `[0, 1, 4]`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class MemBank(object):
    def __init__(self, shared_mem):
        self.mem = dict()
        self.shared_mem = shared_mem

    def fill_mem(self, n):
        print "\tfilling: id, shared_id = %s %s" % (id(self.mem), id(self.shared_mem))
        for i in xrange(n):
            self.mem[i] = i
            self.shared_mem[i] *= self.mem[i]
        print "\tmem = "+str(self.mem)
        print "\tshared_mem = "+str([elt for elt in self.shared_mem])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    P = 2
    n = 3

    # initialize memory banks
    mem_bank = dict()
    shared_mem = mp.Array('f', [1,1,1], lock=True)
    print "shared_id =", id(shared_mem)
    for p in xrange(P):
        mem_bank[p] = MemBank(shared_mem)
        print "p, id, shared_id =", p, id(mem_bank[p].mem), id(mem_bank[p].shared_mem)

    # fill memory banks in parallel
    processes = [mp.Process(target=mem_bank[p].fill_mem, args=(3,)) for p in xrange(P)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    # view the results
    for p in xrange(P):
        bank_p = mem_bank[p]
        print "p, id, shared_id =", p, id(bank_p.mem), id(bank_p.shared_mem)
        print "\tmem =", bank_p.mem
        print "\tshared_mem =", [elt for elt in bank_p.shared_mem]
```

I'm using windows, and the above code is in a module that's part of a python package. To run it, from the command line, I navigate to the package directory, and then do `python -m path.to.module`. The result:

```
C:\path\to\package>python -m package.path.to.module
shared_id = 39625840
p, id, shared_id = 0 39624544 39625840
p, id, shared_id = 1 39649328 39625840
        filling: id, shared_id = 38894304 39278672
        mem = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
        shared_mem = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
        filling: id, shared_id = 39942016 40319056
        mem = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
        shared_mem = [0.0, 1.0, 4.0]
p, id, shared_id = 0 39624544 39625840
        mem = {}        
        shared_mem = [0.0, 1.0, 4.0]
p, id, shared_id = 1 39649328 39625840
        mem = {}        
        shared_mem = [0.0, 1.0, 4.0]
```

My problem: as we can see from the printout, I fill the two `mem`s and compute `shared_mem` in parallel using `multiprocessing` (this is the `fill_mem` method). Everything's fine until I try to view the `mem`s post computation. They show up as empty, even though they were filled during the computation and the `shared_mem` has the correct results. The `mem` attributes do not need to be shared, and I'd like to recover them post computation without making them shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everything's fine until I try to view the `mem`s post computation. They show up as empty, even though they were filled during the computation ...

Ah, but they *weren't*.

Think of `multiprocessing` as the ability to copy yourself<sup>1</sup> to other people and then direct the near-clones, which are now independent people, to do things.  We start off with Jon (the original) and make two copies: Jon0 (`processes[0]`) and Jon1.  We also give each clone a copy (not the original) of the `args=` and a copy (not the original) of the `target=` as well, although usually this doesn't matter much.<sup>2</sup>

Jon0 runs off<sup>3</sup> and does something, with some private data (no one else sees this), and also with the shared thing.  Whenever he wants to read or write the shared thing, he waits in line for the lock if necessary, takes the lock, does the read-or-write, and then releases the lock.  When he's done he vanishes into a cloud of smoke, leaving behind only an exit code.<sup>4</sup>

Jon1 likewise goes off and does something (pretty much the same thing) and eventually vanishes in a cloud of smoke as well.

The original "us", aka Jon, now waits for Jon0 and Jon1 to poof.  Then we go on to print our `mem_bank[0]` and `mem_bank[1]`.  They are completely unchanged, which itself is not surprising.  The surprise *was* that `mem_bank[0].mem[key]` and `mem_bank[1].mem[key]` were unchanged as well ... but now it's less surprising, because we gave Jon0 a *copy* of our empty dictionary `mem_bank[0].mem`.  He modified *his copy*, not our original.  Likewise, Jon1 modified his copy of `mem_bank[1].mem`, not our original.

The only place we see any change is in `shared_mem`, because it has that special sharing type, with associated lock.  Operations on the `shared_mem` `mp.Array` object go into the shared vault, with the fancy "wait for the lock, take the lock, go into the shared vault and do the thing, and then put back the lock" dance.  That includes our (original Jon's) own *reading* of the shared object, even after Jon0 and Jon1 have poofed.  Of course, now that there is no one else taking the lock, we always get it immediately, but there is still a time-cost to accessing these things.

Note that `multiprocessing` and `threading` provide similar creation and join methods.  One key difference between them is that threading does not create totally-independent clones at all, but rather a sort of conjoined-twin: a separate brain inhabiting the same body, as it were.  (Alas, due to the cpython Global Interpreter Lock, many seemingly independent operations that *could* be done in parallel on multiple CPUs wind up single-threaded despite the "threading".)  The rest of the differences mostly exist because as soon as you have independent clones, you find they need shared communications channels, so that they can talk to each other.  Conjoined twins, sharing one body, don't need that: one can just store stuff in its hand and go to sleep, waking up another brain which can then look at its hand.

---

<sup>1</sup>The key difference between Windows Python and Linux/Unix Python is how this copy-to-clone happens.  On a Unix-like system, the clone happens via `os.fork`, copying whatever "you" have so far: all the things you know at this point *also* get copied.  On Windows, however, the clone happens by spawning a fresh (empty) instance of Python, running the same program, but starting the copy running somewhere<sup>5</sup> in the multiprocessing code, with `__name__` not `'__main__'`.

<sup>2</sup>The copy is done via the `pickle` module, converting Python classes and data objects to strings.  The copying process matters a lot when `pickle` fails!  The details on how strings get exchanged with the clone are normally entirely irrelevant, and differ somewhat on Unix and Windows.

<sup>3</sup>This "running off" happens when you call `start`, or shortly afterward.  The clone itself is not created until that point, and once it's created, it reads in the pickled `target`, `args`, and `kwargs`.  Then it calls `self.run`, whose entire code reads:

```
    if self._target:
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

which means you can make a sub-class of `Process` that doesn't use `self._target` and the two arguments, letting you not bother passing any in.  There is little real point to this though: it's just done this way to maintain symmetry with the `Thread` class.

<sup>4</sup>The exit code is passed back through the operating system and is therefore limited to whatever the OS provides.

<sup>5</sup>The way this is managed on Windows is especially tricky.  Essentially, the original process spawns a new Python command with command-line arguments:

```
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        return [sys.executable, '--multiprocessing-fork']
    else:
        prog = 'from multiprocessing.forking import main; main()'
        opts = util._args_from_interpreter_flags()
        return [_python_exe] + opts + ['-c', prog, '--multiprocessing-fork']
```

This complicated method allows the `multiprocessing` module to (in most cases at least) detect code that fails to use the correct programming idioms (both to protect against endless recursion, and to invoke the special multiprocessing freeze-support code in the `__main__` section if needed).

It's much easier on Unix-like systems, where `multiprocessing` can just call `os.fork` to make a clone that is just about to return from an `os.fork` call.  The new clone knows he's the clone because *his* `os.fork` call returns 0, while the original knows he's the original because *his* `os.fork` call returns the ID of the clone.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was very good! Is there an easy way to replace the original Jon's `mem_bank` with the updated `mem_bank`s from Jon0 and Jon1 before those processes "go poof"?

Comment: There are multiple ways, with varying efficiency considerations. They fall into two groups: *shared* things (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) or *exchanged* things (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes). The way to think about this is that shared things require cooperation so that the sharers don't step on each other, so exchanged things are "safer"/easier, but exchanging things requires converting to/from pickled form. You pick where you want to pay which cost.

Comment: (The above links to py2k docs but py3k is basically the same here.) The other issue with exchanging is that you might have to stop-and-wait in a consumer, for a producer to produce something. Exchange via queue is particularly efficient if you have some producers and some consumers and can simply consume in whatever order as produced in whatever order; then you can use a `Queue` with multiple producers and consumers. If you need stronger ordering, you can use multiple Queues or some other mechanism(s).